# How to give Ubuntu 16 more space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, unmount

I know this question was answered a thousand times but I can't find a solution. So here's what I have:

128Gb SSD with Windows 10 installed
1Tb HDD with a partition of about 80Gb that I used to install Ubuntu 16 (I am still asking myself why I didn't give it more space in the first place).

I now need to give Ubuntu more space from the HDD. I tried unallocating some space from Windows (5Gb) and while in Ubuntu I tried to follow the instructions here: [How to give Ubuntu 14.04 more disk space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502781/how-to-give-ubuntu-14-04-more-disk-space) but I can't unmount /dev/sda2.

[image]

How can I give Ubuntu more space then? Also what are exactly /dev/sda2, /dev/sda3, /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6? I thought Ubuntu had only one partition. Which one should get extended?

Thank you

Comment: The instructions assume you're running GParted from a **live session**. You can't resize/move partitions that are in use.

Comment: You cannot unmount sda2 because you are using it, it is your root partition.

Comment: Ok, I just learned that I live session is when you start from a CD/USB drive. Which partition is supposed to get the unallocated space though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where to allocate space**

Your comments have already cleared that you need to run `gparted` from a live session so that it won't be mounted when re-partitioning the drive.

Looking at your image, Ubuntu is installed on partition `/dev/sda2`.  That is also the partition where you are critically low in space.  So you should assign the unllocated space to that partition where it's needed.

**What are exactly /dev/sda2, /dev/sda3, /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6?**

Ubuntu only uses one partition as you thought.  However a default installation will make a swap partition for increased performance.  It's not a requirement.  Also, there is an option to separate partitions for specific folders.  People commonly create a separate partition for their home folder (`/home`).  This isn't a requirement either, but is done for convenience for the occasions for reinstalling Ubuntu or moving to a different system and being sure to maintain their personal space untouched.

```
/dev/sda2    - The root installation of Ubuntu
/dev/sda3    - A primary partition that can be devided into logical partitions.
               The logical partition functions just like regular partitions.  This
               overcomes the 4 partition limit of a MBR hard drive.
/dev/sda5    - A swap partition.  This is a partition that used to function as if
               it were RAM.  It allows RAM to be swapped to the hard drive, freeing
               up RAM for other tasks.
/dev/sda6    - Your Home folder.  Setup for your personal space.
```